# Как отформатировать флешку?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, fat32

Не могу отформатировать флешку после ее использования как установочной для CentOS на другом компьютере, rufus и diskpart не помогли, какие еще средства могут помочь я не знаю.

Comment: Что значит «не помогли»? Что не получается? Что мешает взять какой-нибудь банальный gparted?

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`. Если флэшка - `sdb`.

Comment: под linux на отмонтированную флешку сделайте `wipefs -a /dev/sdX`, где вместо sdX пропишите свою флешку, а после уже форматируйте как вам надо.

Comment: @donRumata что за глупости...

Comment: @eri, почему? Судя по вопросу - после экспериментов с созданием загрузочной флэшкой - она перестала "нормально" работать, потому что на ней остался мусор типа efi разделов, кастомных загрузчиков и прочего. `dd` отлично решает эту проблему убирая с флэшки (как и с любого другого "файла") вообще всё что найдёт. Вернее забивая это всё нулями. Я этим приёмом пользовался неоднократно ровно после подобных попыток, когда "умные" форматировалки рассказывали, что не могут удалить раздел или переписать загрузчик.